# What's the initial position of the Frame Pointer

Tags: cpu-registers, instruction-set

When we call a function, we will make use of Stack Pointer and Framer Pointer.
I know the function and initial position of SP, but how about FP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is dependent on architecture, and should be documented in the ABI manual.

Typically, functions do not rely on the frame pointer being properly initialized before the prologue, but rather just store the value on the stack and subsequently set the frame pointer to the current stack pointer (so by following the frame pointer, you find the frame pointer for the previous function at a fixed offset).

Keep in mind that the frame pointer is optional most of the time (you need it if you do not have debugging information and want to follow the call stack, or if the current function used `alloca`, otherwise it is just a register going to waste.